# IE9 F12 Developer Tools - What's the difference between "Load(event)" and "page has finished loading"?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to understand some of the output of Internet Explorer 9's F12 Developer Tools Network tab.

On http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/linqed/2010/10/06/network-traffic-capturing-with-ie9-developer-tools/

[image]

Microsoft defines "Gap" as "the time gap between the completion of the request and the time the whole page has finished loading" but in the above example, you can see that the Gap extends well past the "Load(event)".

So, what could be going on in the browser between "Load(event)" and "the whole page has finished loading". Is it just the Javascript code registered with the onloadevent? Or does something else happen then?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbowen/archive/2011/07/08/internet-explorer-9-developer-tools-deep-dive-part-5-network-performance-and-debugging.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that any Ajax request triggered after the onLoad event will cause the Gap to extend past the Load(event)

My confusion arose because I had Ajax requests that were triggered X seconds after the page was loaded, so it depended on when I looked at the Network tab whether I saw the extra requests/the Gap extending past Load(event).

For example see the summary view here, where the last request is an Ajax request after the red-line/Load(event).

[image]

And this shows up in the Detailed view as

[image]

I would also argue that Microsoft's wording is wrong. You can't really say that the page is ready only after the Ajax request. For many pages, they will be ready once the onLoad event has happened and Ajax will bring in updates.

Answer (score 1):

The `DOMContentLoaded` event fires as soon as the HTML page (and its scripts) has been loaded and parsed.

Things like external stylesheets and images are requested asynchronously, so it will take a little longer for all these requests to come back. When they have come back, the `load` event is triggered. This event is what IE9 calls `Load(event)`.

A good illustration is found [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In the above diagram, "onDomContentLoaded" (the green-line) and "Load(event)" are separate events, aren't they?

Comment: Sorry! Couldn't see your image previously. Will amend my answer.

Comment: Ah, I think I can see what's causing the confusion. You've included the image from the article you link to - but in that image the diagram and the durations seem to be wrong, as the Gap is supposed to be the amount of time from the start of the page loading process until the firing of Load(event).

Comment: If you use the Developer Tools to record network traffic yourself, you should see that the red line is on the far right, where the vertical black line is on your diagram.

Comment: That's what prompted to post this. I can consistently get F12 Developer Tools locally, to show me a Gap which extends well past the Load (event) red-line. So either Developer tools has a bug in it, or how I think it should work is different from how it is working.

Comment: That's really weird. It certainly looks fine for me in IE10. Perhaps it's an IE9-specific bug.